# Erro ao gerar título da seção referências quando uso o pacote amsmath

Tags: latex, abntex2

Estou preparando um trabalho e para isso preciso usar chaves no modo de equações como a seguir:

```
\begin{equation}
\Delta \eta_{i,j} = 
   \begin{cases}
     \eta_{i,j},&  se\quad aresta\quad i,j\quad foi\quad utilizada \\
      0,        &  se\quad aresta\quad i,j\quad n\tilde{a}o\quad foi\quad utilizada
   \end{cases}
\label{eq5}
\end{equation}
```

Para isso preciso utilizar o

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Contudo, quando uso esse pacote (já fiz o teste incluindo e removendo o mesmo, é ele sim quem gera o erro) na chamada do comando

```
\bibliography{referencias}
```

para gerar minhas referências o título da seção sai errado. Dessa forma

```
7  *
    Referências
```

Sem formatação nenhuma. Não era para ser numerada inclusive essa seção.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Não sei o que está havendo.

Comment: ... "é ele sim quem gera o erro" : qual o mensagem de erro?

Comment: Sem a mensagem de erro, fica mesmo muito difícil saber qual é o problema. Talvez seja [esse aqui](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146744/amsmath-bibliography-conflict)? De todas as formas, prepare um exemplo mínimo compilável que reproduza o problema e poste ele na sua pergunta, senão nós nem temos como testar uma sugestão de resolução.

Answer (score 0):

A definição de função está correcta (e funciona perfeitamente)
(verifica só se o `\usepackage{...}` está no preambulo (i.e. antes do
`\begin{document}`)

---

a questão da bibiografia é algo completamente diferente

`\bibliography{referencias}` indica que tens um ficheiro externo (`referencias.bib`) contendo referências bibliográficas.

Isto poderá dar erros em diversas situações. Exemplo:

- o ficheiro não existir;
- existir mas não estar na sintaxe certe,
- não haver nenhuma citação bibliográfica
  ( `\cite{chave}`),
- ou se usares citações a chaves que não estejam definidas.

Se for este o caso: corrige os respectivos erros ou comenta ou retira
o `\bibliography{referencias}`